# PHP display $variable in HTML before it is defined

Tags: php, html

I have a webpage called search.php

I want it to have a title/tab tag that looks like this:

```
<head>
  <title><?php echo $number_count; ?> items found - Mysearch </title>
<head>
```

But the variable $number_count is 0 until later php scripts are called to query the database and display the items one at a time. At the end of the HTML I can easily display `<p> <?php echo $number_count; echo "items found" ?> </p>` and it works with the correct count.

Comment: No you can't display the value of a variable until it's been assigned that value; in practise, it's generally better to get all your data before displaying it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be defined first.
Best (and only in this case) approach to do it is to do calculations first, then generate website output.

EDIT:

You can do it like that:

```
<?php 

$count = 125;

?><!DOCTYPE html>
....

<title>Title count: <?php echo $count ?></title>
....
```

Comment: Can I define the title of the html at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Updated answear with an example.